# Is it ok to say "a map is identical"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Is it ok to say that a map $f: X \rightarrow X$ is identical, to mean that it is the identity map?

I believe this terminology would allow one to write statements such as

"The restriction of $g: X \rightarrow X$ to $X' \subset X$ is equal to the identity map on $X'$"

with much less text., i.e.:

"The restriction of $g: X \rightarrow X$ to $X' \subset X$ is identical"

and remaining "smooth" i.e. without using too many symbols (this is a subjective notion but I hope it is understandable).

For me this intuitively doesn't sound quite correct, but a google search shows a few authors have used this phrase and my intuition on such matters has been wrong in the past.

Therefore, I have decided ask here to get a more general consensus.  I would also appreciate someone could point out a textbook where it is used (although I doubt this somehow).

Comment: To me, and my English knowledge, "identical" is a word which compares two things, not a property that a single thing can have. So I would never use it like that.

Comment: I would find that very odd, and would suspect the author was not a native English speaker. It makes perfect *sense*; it's just *odd*. "Identical" almost always appears  as a comparison between things ("the twins were identical", "You solution is identical to Robin's") rather than as a characterization of a single item.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but this sounds just wrong to me. The first reaction I have to "the restriction ... is identical" is: "identical to what, exactly"? You can just say "the restriction ... is the identity map". Two more words, but a lot more clear.

Comment: You could even go with "the restriction is the identity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.  This would be incorrect terminology...  You say a map is *the identity* when $m(x)=x\;\forall x \in X$.